# Consulta en array guardado en PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql

Tengo almacenado un conjusto de datos con un campo tipo JSON llamado data. En el almaceno algo así:

```
{"allocation_criteria":["1","2","22"],"bonus_type_awarded":"2","percentage":1.5}
```

Y quiero hacer una consulta que me retorne todos los registros de la tabla que en el atributo allocation_criteria posean el valor 2 por ejemplo. Intente utilizando IN y ANY pero ninguno me funciona.

He intentado algo similar a esto pero no funciona:

```
select id,  data->'allocation_criteria'  as allocation
FROM campaigns
WHERE data->'allocation_criteria' in ('2')
```

O tal vez deba guardar la información de otra manera.

Comment: ¿Falta el `WHERE`? (No aceptes la edición a tu código por cierto, debés ser vos quien corrija la consulta en la pregunta).

Comment: Me faltaba el WHERE porque la consulta es más larga y solo deje el fragmento que me interesaba y no me percate de eso

Comment: En ese caso, editá como corresponde el código. Y por cierto, [fijate por qué te decía que rechaces la edición](/review/suggested-edits/351922).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que estas retornando con esa expresión (`data->'allocation_criteria'`) un json, para poder comparar debes hacer algunos "casteos" o transformaciones, como por ejemplo llevarlo a un `ARRAY` y luego usar un operador de `ARRAY`

```sql
select  id,data->'allocation_criteria'  as allocation
from campaigns
 where 
string_to_array( right(left(replace((data->'allocation_criteria')::text,'"',''),-1),-1),',') @> ARRAY['2']
```